# AutoMapper: Max graph depth

Tags: c#, automapper-3

I have the following entities which are connected with lists:

Country -> Region -> Municipality -> Street

When I map a Country object to my DTO, AutoMapper automatically projects my entire graph, all the way down to Streets, which is a great default. 
In a specific usecase I would like to map just the root object (Country) and its immediate children (Regions). These regions should then have en empty list of Municipalities (or null).

One way to achieve this is to create a map like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Data.Country, Dto.Country>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Data.Region, Dto.Region>()
  .ForMember(dest => dest.Municipalities, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

This would mean that when projecting a Region as the root object, its list of Municipalities will be ignored. A workaround for this is to create separate ConfigurationStore objects for each possible root object, but that would result in a lot of different ConfigurationStores. Is there any way to tell AutoMapper to only map down to a certain depth in the object graph?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can define map specific `MaxDepth` like so:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Destination>().MaxDepth(1);
```

More info:
https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Attribute-mapping.html?highlight=maxdepth

Comment: how to set this for all maps? Like a default value for MaxDepth

Answer (score 4):

To set the max depth for all mapped items:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
     cfg.ForAllMaps((typeMap, mappingExpression) => mappingExpression.MaxDepth(1));
}
```

or

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
     cfg.ForAllMaps(SetMaxDepth);
}

private static void SetMaxDepth(TypeMap typeMap, IMappingExpression expression)
{
     expression.MaxDepth(1);
}
```